# I get an error when running this program in C#: no overload for method 'Movies' takes '0' arguments. I need a method that does it

Tags: c#, methods

I want a method that gets input from the user, loops through the input, sorts the words that the user entered, and prints them sorted. (by the way, the language is c#). When I run the program, I get an error:

> no overload for method 'Movies' takes '0' arguments"

there is the Main method but I couldn't put that in the code because StackOverflow will give me an error. the main method calls the method written below like this: `Movies();`

note: I am young and new to programming.
I know that I could do it just using the main method but I wanted to see what happens if I did that.

```
using System;

favoriteMovies = new string[4];


Console.WriteLine("Enter four movies: ");

for (int i = 0; i < favoriteMovies.Length; i++)
{
  favoriteMovies[i] = Console.ReadLine();
} 
Console.WriteLine("Here are the movies sorted alphabetically: ");

Array.Sort(favoriteMovies);

for (int i = 0; i < favoriteMovies.Length; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(favoriteMovies[i]);
}
return favoriteMovies;
}
```

Comment: C# is not python, you cannot just write code anywhere. The code needs to be inside a method, and that method needs to live inside a class. Also, that code doesn't compile, so you are not running it, it's failing before that

Comment: *but I couldn't put that in the code because StackOverflow will give me an error* -  what error? How can we tell you if you don't show the function itself and the call to it. Anyway, ther error message says that the method needs an argument, which you didn't pass in the call.

Comment: please post at least your class, complete Main method and Movies method .I guess that's only an uncomplete snippet of your code

Comment: I did this doing the code only inside the Main() method and it worked, but my question is how do I make a method that does what I want, and call that method inside the Main() method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you don't show us more of your code, it is hard to guess where the error is. But I guess you write `public static string[] Movies(var argument)` instead of `public static string[] Movies()`
Here is what it would need to look like:

```
    using System;
    namespace Program{
        class Program{
            public static void Main(string[] args){
                Movies();
            }

            public static string[] Movies(){
                var favoriteMovies = new string[4];

                Console.WriteLine("Enter four movies: ");

                for (int i = 0; i < favoriteMovies.Length; i++)
                {
                    favoriteMovies[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Here are the movies sorted alphabetically: ");

                Array.Sort(favoriteMovies);

                foreach (string i in favoriteMovies)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }

                return favoriteMovies;
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help you!
If not, please clarify your question!

Comment: you do not to declare any method if you use C# 9 :) see my answer to find out more

Comment: I did this doing the code only inside the Main() method and it worked, but my question is how do I make a method that does what I want, and call that method inside the Main() method.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry I missed the point! I answered this question when it still looked different (since then, it got edited).